# Use expression with a variable r

Tags: r, expression

I am trying to label a plot with the following label:

"Some Assay EC50 (uM)" where the "u" is a micro symbol.

I currently have:

```
assay <- "Some Assay"
plot(0,xlab=expression(paste(assay," AC50 (",mu,"M)",sep="")))
```

But that gives: "assay EC50 (uM)" rather than the desired "Some Assay EC50 (uM)".

Suggestions? Thanks.

I also tried:

```
paste(assay,expression(paste(" AC50 (",mu,"M)",sep="")),sep="")
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You want a combination of `bquote()` and a bit of plotmath fu:

```
assay <- "Some Assay"
xlab <- bquote(.(assay) ~ AC50 ~ (mu*M))
plot(0, xlab = xlab)
```

The `~` is a spacing operator and `*` means juxtapose the contents to the left and right of the operator. In `bquote()`, anything wrapped in `.( )` will be looked up and replaced with the value of the named object; so `.(assay)` will be replaced in the expression with `Some Assay`.

Answer (score 9):

Using tidy_eval approach you could do

```
library(rlang)

assay <- "Some Assay"
plot(0,xlab=expr(paste(!!assay," AC50 (",mu,"M)",sep="")))
```

expr and !! are included in tidyverse, so you don't actually need to load rlang. I just put it there to be explicit about where they come from.

Answer (score 2):

another option using `mtext` and bquote

```
plot(0,xlab='')
Lines <- list(bquote(paste(assay," AC50 (",mu,"M)",sep="")))
mtext(do.call(expression, Lines),side=1,line=3)
```

Note that I set the xlab to null in the first plot.

**EDIT**
No need to call expression, since bquote will create an expression with replacement of elements wrapped in .( ) by their value. So a goodanswer is :

```
plot(0,xlab='')
Lines <- bquote(paste(.(assay)," AC50 (",mu,"M)",sep=""))
mtext(Lines,side=1,line=3)
```

Comment: That defeats the point of `bquote()` which is to form an expression with replacement of elements wrapped in `.( )` by their value.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks I get your point. Does it look better now?

Comment: Not sure why, but I had to use `do.call(expression, Lines)` to make expression expanded, using the after-edit suggestion wrote literally the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You also could try the poor man's approach:

```
assay <- "Some Assay"
plot(0, xlab = paste0(assay, " AC50 (µM)"))
```

It specifies the mu character directly rather than using expressions (and `paste0` is just `paste` with `sep = ""`).