# Two font faces in ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-face

I am trying to create a bar plot with two font faces for the y labels (don't confuse: it's called x due to `coord_flip()`). 
However, I have not found any solution for this on the internet.

Is it even possible?

I've got this so far.

```
library(ggplot2)

labs <- paste(rep("1st", 40), rep("2nd", 40), rep("3rd", 40))
labs <- strsplit(labs, " ")

v1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:40, y = 1:40), aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey50") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(sapply(labs, "[[", 1), 
                                  .(bold(.(sapply(labs, "[[", 2)))),
                                  sapply(labs, "[[", 3)), 
                   breaks = 1:40)
v1
```

I want to be the `2nd` in all ylabs as bold face. 
Yet, I get this: [image]

The tick labels should look like this ([=====] indicate the bars in the plot):

1st **2nd** 3rd   [================================]

1st **2nd** 3rd   [=============================]

1st **2nd** 3rd   [==========================]

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### minimal example

You have to define an `expression`.

```
library(ggplot2)

all.data <- data.frame(group=c('a','b'),count=c(5,8))

ggplot(data=all.data, aes(group, count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label=c( expression(paste("xxx",bold("foo"))), expression(paste("yyy",bold("bar")))  ))
```

[image]

#### example using variables

A post here on stackoverflow got me on the right track:
[Use expression with a variable r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074127/use-expression-with-a-variable-r)

```
labs <- paste(rep("1st", 40), rep("2nd", 40), rep("3rd", 40))
labs <- strsplit(labs, " ")

# create a vector of expressions
# everything in .() is evaluated and ~ forms an expression
plot.labs <- bquote( .(labs[[1]][1]) ~ bold(.(labs[[1]][2])) ~ .(labs[[1]][3]))

# produce a list of expressions
plot.labs.apply <- lapply(labs, function(x) {plot.labs <- bquote( .(x[1]) ~ bold(.(x[2])) ~ .(x[3]))})

# was it done correctly?
class(plot.labs.apply[[2]])

# i used a smaller data frame to not overload the plot
ggplot(data.frame(x = c('a','b'), y = c(40,25)), aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey50") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_x_discrete(label = c(plot.labs.apply) )
```

[image]

Comment: It may work for this minimal example. However, it is not possible to create the labels dynamically with expressions. Thus it would be useful, if you use the example I put in the question.

Comment: Added an example using variables. Hope it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

#### general

You need to change the axis.text.x instead of working directly on the scale.x.discrete.

As a side comment to create your `labs` vector, you can use:

```
labs <- rep( c("1st","2nd","3rd"), 40)
font.faces <- rep( c("plain","bold","plain"), 40 )
```

The bold/plain face can be done like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# have some example data
all.data <- data.frame(group=c('a','b'),count=c(5,8))

ggplot(data=all.data, aes(group, count)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
 # put your names here
 scale_x_discrete(label=c("foo","bar")) + 
 # put a vector assigning bold and plain here
 # e.g. you can put font.faces vector here if you have 40 labels
 theme( axis.text.x = element_text(face=c("bold","plain")) )
```

#### example

A more explicit example would be this one. Please make sure that the error about unequal amounts of elements in your ggplot statement does not result from the fact that your sample naming on the x-axis (y-axis after flipping) are repetitive. They may need to be unique.

```
# generate some data
all.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(30), nrow = 30, ncol = 1))

# produce labels and font faces
# labels need to be unique to make sure ggplot2 doesn't summarise the categories
labs <- rep( c("1st","2nd","3rd"), 10)
labs.ext <- paste(labs, rep(seq(10), each=3), sep='_')
font.faces <- rep( c("plain", "bold", "plain"), 10)

# add a label column to the data frame (and make sure that it will be a  factor with levels in your intended order)
all.data[,2] <- factor(labs.ext, levels = labs.ext)
colnames(all.data) <- c("count","name")

# including your coord_flip(), x axis transforms to y axis
ggplot(data=all.data, aes(name, count)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = font.faces)) + coord_flip()
```

[image: example]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution just applies a bold face to the first tick-label and a plain face to the second. However, I am looking for a way to create three-part tick labels which look like this: 1st **2nd** 3rd. This setting should be applied to each individual tick label. I edited the question

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly. I think a long vector that contains explicit bold, plain for each label should fix it.

Comment: No, that's not working because of unequal lenth of breaks and labels. I would highly appreciate an example figure, if it worked for you. Thx

Comment: the unequal length could result from your input names (1st, 2nd, 3rd) being repetitive. Added a picture and the according code to get there.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. pls check it again. Anyways, thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: You're right. After your edits and re-reading several times - it's clear i got it wrong.

Comment: Probably my fault too. Yet, i was able to redefine my question with your comments.