# How to evaluate a varible inside an expression to use as an axis label?

Tags: r

I am trying to evaluate a variable inside the`expression` function. The function works fine when the variable has no value and is just a string.

```
> plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(value~2^-dCT))
```

[image]

But when value is a variable, the value of the variable gets ignored...

```
> rm(value)
> value = "some text"
```

```
> plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(value~2^-dCT))
```

[image]

I also tried `> plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(eval(value)~2^-dCT))` and had a similar issue...
[image]

`plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(paste(value~2^-dCT)))` does not work as well. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: see e.g. `?bquote`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. It brought me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074127/use-expression-with-a-variable-r) where the same question was asked. My bad, I was not aware this function existed.

Comment: No need for an apology; if you knew, you wouldn't need to ask (and searching for duplicates on SO is unfortunately not that easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several ways:

```
value <- "some text"

# 1
plot(0, xlab = substitute(value ~ 2^-dCT, list(value = value)))

# 2
plot(0, xlab = bquote(.(value) ~ 2^-dCT))

# 3
plot(0, xlab = parse(text = sprintf("'%s' ~ 2^-dCT", value)))

# 4
fo <- value ~ 2^-dCT
fo[[2]] <- as.name(value)
plot(0, xlab = fo)
```

Comment: I'll accept this since you wrote out the answer. Thank you as well!